# Not deleting pointer? What? How does this work

Tags: c++, pointers

So long story short, I was writing code for my game and couldn't get it to work. I was initializing some pointers and then decided to NOT delete the pointers I was allocating and then magically started working. What is going on? I'm super confused.

The reason why I decided to get rid of the pointer was because of code I found at this link.

[Game State Machine - GameDevGeek](http://gamedevgeek.com/files/stateman.zip)

GameStatesMachine.h

```
#ifndef __GAMESTATESMACHINE_H__
#define __GAMESTATESMACHINE_H__

#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "GameStates.h"

class GameStatesMachine
{
private:
    std::vector<GameStates *> data;

    GameStatesMachine() {};
    GameStatesMachine(GameStatesMachine const&);
    void operator=(GameStatesMachine const&);
    // you do not delete it this is for cleaning purposes
    ~GameStatesMachine()
    {
        while (!data.empty())
            pop_back();

        printf("GameEngine cleanup\n");
    }
public:
    static GameStatesMachine& Instance()
    {
        static GameStatesMachine g_instance;
        return g_instance;
    }

    void push_back(GameStates * state);
    void pop_back();
    void changeState(GameStates * state); 

    void render();
    void process();
    void update();
};

#endif
```

GameStatesMachine.cpp

```
#include "GameStatesMachine.h"

void GameStatesMachine::push_back(GameStates * state)
{
    if (!data.empty())
        data.back()->pause();
    data.push_back(state);
    data.back()->onEnter();
}

void GameStatesMachine::pop_back()
{
    if (!data.empty()) {
        data.back()->onExit();
        data.pop_back();
    }
    if (!data.empty())
        data.back()->resume();

}

void GameStatesMachine::changeState(GameStates * state)
{
    if (!data.empty())
        pop_back();
    push_back(state);
}

void GameStatesMachine::render()
{
    data.back()->render();
}

void GameStatesMachine::process()
{
    data.back()->process();
}

void GameStatesMachine::update()
{
    data.back()->update();
}
```

Comment: What pointer are you deleting, and where are you deleting it?

Comment: I _was_ deleting it in pop_back() after data.back()->onExit(); and before data.pop_back();
the pointer is just a Object called states.
The code wasn't working, so looking online for examples of what other people did and noticing that one guy didn't delete it, I decided to copy him and then my code magically worked. Shouldn't not deleting it create a memory leak? Or would vector pop_back just call the deconstructor for me?

Comment: It's hard for us to solve the mystery if you don't give us enough code to reproduce the error -- and it's almost impossible if you don't tell us what the error is.

Answer (score 3):

I took a look at the sample code in the link. Basically I think this boils down to a misunderstanding on when you need to call delete.

Basically, you only need to call delete when you use new. None of the sample code in the link use new, instead the engine pushes and pops static states:

```
class CPlayState : public CGameState
{
    static CPlayState* Instance() {
        return &m_PlayState;
    }

    // other code

private:
    static CPlayState m_PlayState;
}
```

How CPlayState is used:

```
void CIntroState::HandleEvents(CGameEngine* game)
{
    // other code.
    game->ChangeState( CPlayState::Instance() );
}
```

Basically the game engine pushes and pops those static states rather than calling new to instantiate them. Since the object isn't created with new, you don't call delete on it. Since they are static, they are cleaned up when your process exits.

There are better resources to learn C++ scoping logic and object lifetimes and I would recommend going to Google to find them.